# TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'

Tags: python, salesforce

```
import beatbox
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from datetime import *
import datetime as dt
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from datetime import datetime
query_result= [{'End_Date__c': datetime.date(2018, 7, 20), 'User_Email__c': 'jsmith@test-account.com', 'ProductVersion__c': '1', 'Product_Name__c': 'Payor', 'itil_b__Account__r': {'type': 'Account', 'Id': '', 'Customer_Short_Name__c': 'TESTACCT'}, 'Target_Environment__r': {'type': 'Environment__c', 'Id': '', 'Name': 'TEST-PROD'}, 'type': 'itil_b__Fulfillment__c', 'Id': 'a3sc0000000CiZpAAK'}, {'End_Date__c': datetime.date(2018, 7, 19), 'User_Email__c': 'jsmith@test-account.com', 'ProductVersion__c': '4', 'Product_Name__c': 'CareManager', 'itil_b__Account__r': {'type': 'Account', 'Id': '', 'Customer_Short_Name__c': 'TESTACCT'}, 'Target_Environment__r': {'type': 'Environment__c', 'Id': '', 'Name': 'TEST-NONPROD'}, 'type': 'itil_b__Fulfillment__c', 'Id': 'a3sc0000000CiAyAAK'}]

record=query_result['records']
df=pd.DataFrame(records)
print df
```

When I execute above python script, I am getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    query_result= [{'End_Date__c': datetime.date(2018, 7, 20), 'User_Email__c': 'jsmith@test-account.com', 'ProductVersion__c': '1', 'Product_Name__c': 'Payor', 'itil_b__Account__r': {'type': 'Account', 'Id': '', 'Customer_Short_Name__c': 'TESTACCT'}, 'Target_Environment__r': {'type': 'Environment__c', 'Id': '', 'Name': 'TEST-PROD'}, 'type': 'itil_b__Fulfillment__c', 'Id': 'a3sc0000000CiZpAAK'},  {'End_Date__c':datetime.date(2018, 7, 19), 'User_Email__c': 'jsmith@test-account.com', 'ProductVersion__c': '4', 'Product_Name__c': 'CareManager','itil_b__Account__r': {'type': 'Account', 'Id': '', 'Customer_Short_Name__c': 'TESTACCT'}, 'Target_Environment__r': {'type': 'Environment__c', 'Id': '', 'Name': 'TEST-NONPROD'}, 'type': 'itil_b__Fulfillment__c', 'Id': 'a3sc0000000CiAyAAK'}]
TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

The input I am passing to query_result got from a salesforce soap Api.

Please help me to resolve this issue..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check and edit your question, it is badly formatted and unreadable

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change your import statement from:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

to

```
import datetime
```

As when you say `from datetime import datetime` you are just importing one method and that and not the whole module. And you haven't imported the `date` method.
You could also do this:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date(2018, 9, 20)
datetime.date(2018, 9, 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

datetime(2018, 7, 20).date()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality". Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.